# Inserting data to table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

currently I have three table: test, contact and staff

test

```
FirstName LastName
```

Contact

```
Contact_Id   Contact_FirstName Contact_LastName
```

staff

```
Staff_ID Contact_Id
```

The Staff Id should be auto-increment, I need a script that go through all row in test table. If the FirstName and LastName Matches Contact_FirstName and Contact_LastName. Add Matched Contact_ID number to the Contact_Id thats in the Staff table.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO `staff` (`Contact_Id`)
SELECT c.`ContactId`
FROM   `Contact` c
JOIN   `Test` t ON c.`Contact_FirstName` = t.`FirstName` AND
                   c.`Contact_LastName` = t.`LastName`
```

Answer (score 0):

First change the structure of Staff table by adding IDENTITY in CREATE statement if you want it to be auto-incremented.

CREATE TABLE Staff (StaffID INT IDENTITY, ContactID INT)

now try this to insert just contactID because IDENTITY allows you to skip that column, sql creates those IDs for you.

INSERT Staff SELECT Contact_ID FROM Contact c JOIN Test t ON c.Contact_FirstName=t.FirstName and c.Contact_LastName=t.LastName

this seems like it's checking contact names of Contact based on Contact names of Test.. but this should work if you pass name of person in place of t.FirstName and t.LastName